# Define Matlab function depending from another function

Tags: functions, matlab

I have a function $\phi(x,t)$ and I want to define a function $f$ whose values depend on $\phi$. Specifically:

$$f(x,t) = \begin{cases}6\phi(x,t)+1, & \text{if }\phi(x,t) < 0 \\
2\phi(x,t), & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

In Matlab I tried:

```
function g = f(x,t)  
if phi(x,t) < 0  
    g = 6*phi(x,t)+1;  
else   
    g = 2*phi(x,t);  
end
```

But it doesn't work. Any advice?

Comment: What's going wrong?  Is the file phi.m in your path?

Comment: No, phi works fine, it's just that f will take the value 2*phi(x,t) regardless of the value of phi(x,t) for all x and t. I should mention that phi is 0 at x=1.25 and t=0.5, and I'm plotting f for x=0..2 and t=0.5, so I should see a jump, but it simply doesn't happen

Comment: Without knowing $\phi$ it is difficult to know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will only work if `phi(x,t)` returns a scalar. If it returns a non-scalar array, you'll get an error. And presumably if `x` and/or `t` is non-scalar then `phi(x,t)` will have the same dimensions? With that assumption, here is one way you can adapt your function:

```
function g = f(x,t)
pxt = phi(x,t);
g = zeros(size(pxt));
i0 = (pxt < 0);
g(i0) = 6*pxt(i0)+1;
g(~i0) = 2*pxt(~i0);
```

Comment: Wow, it works. Thanks a lot!
Since it's a 1D project, both x and t are scalar.
Sorry, I didn't think phi(x,t) was important. For information's sake, here it is: `phi(x,t) = x+2*((t-0.75)^2)-1.25;`